# linking dictionary to custom initialiser terminating - reason: '-[__NSCFArray isFileURL]:

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

please be patient im a nuubie at this
I'm writing a custom init for first time, the **sentance01text** loads fine so i know the plist is reading ok :) but i cant seem to get my **sentance01Timing** timings to work ><

this method should pass the **sentance01Timing** typed by the user which is the objectForKey which should load the relevant array into the **audioIntervals array**

at the moment I'm using an NSString to access the dictionary and pass this to the array **audiointervals**
but this seems to be wrong and causes the error anyhelp would be appreciated.
i dont understand why it worked for the text but not this?
 **terminating  - reason: '-[__NSCFArray isFileURL]:**

probably Im doing something really dumb >< please help if you can
ps am having to use my old mac (my nice one is being repaired at the moment - so will be using non arc - then updating the code when I get my nice mac back, so just keep it in mind
its why im not releasing any objects at the moment...)

HelloWorld.m

```
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "TextWithAudioHilight.h"

@implementation HelloWorldLayer

+(CCScene *) scene
{
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
[scene addChild: layer];
return scene;
}


-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {
    TextWithAudioHilight *pagetext = [[TextWithAudioHilight   alloc]initWith5:@"test words here,\nmore words, more words.." 
                                                           sentance01Timing:@"TimingSEN01" 
                                                             withSoundNamed:nil];
    [self addChild:pagetext];
}
return self;
}


- (void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

TextWithAudio.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface TextWithAudioHilight : CCLayer {

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *sentance01text;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *sentance01Timing;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *soundNamed;

-(id)initWith5:(NSString *)sentance01text sentance01Timing:(NSString *)sentance01Timing withSoundNamed:(NSString *)soundNamed;

@end
```

TextWithAudio.m

```
#import "TextWithAudioHilight.h"

@implementation TextWithAudioHilight

@synthesize sentance01text = _sentance01text;
@synthesize sentance01Timing = _sentance01Timing;
@synthesize soundNamed = _soundNamed;

-(id)initWith5:(NSString *)sentance01text sentance01Timing:(NSString *)sentance01Timing  withSoundNamed:(NSString *)soundNamed
 {
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AudioTimings" ofType:@"plist"]; 
    NSDictionary* myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    //needs create array that has timing information as an array from the plist
    //NSString *Text01timing = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"sentance01Timing"];
    NSString *Text01timing = [myDictionary objectForKey:_sentance01Timing];
    NSMutableArray * audioIntervals = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:Text01timing];
                                              NSLog(@"Text01timing %f",audioIntervals);


    //needs to create a label and put the text in it
    CGSize maxSize = {800, 200};
    CGSize actualSize = [sentance01text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]
    constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGSize containerSize = { actualSize.width, actualSize.height };
    CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:sentance01text dimensions:containerSize
                alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Helvetica"
                                           fontSize:20];

    // Center label
    label.position = ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/6 );
    label.color = ccc3(80, 80, 80);
    // Add label to this scene
    [self addChild:label z:7];


}
return self;
}
@end
```

AudioTimings.plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>TimingSEN01</key>
<array>
    <real>0.044444</real>
    <real>0.143054</real>
    <real>0.213886</real>
    <real>0.48055</real>
    <real>0.844434</real>
    <real>1.345817</real>
    <real>1.470816</real>
    <real>1.577759</real>
    <real>2.020809</real>
    <real>2.331917</real>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: hmmm it will be my understanding of how to get what the user types and passing it that im stuck on... ill update the code and try to explain my thought process (since most likely thats the faulty thing :P), thank you for looking :)

Comment: Sorry my comments are way-off.  Need more information.  What does `_sentance01Timing` contain?  Is it a filename (if so name the variable better).  Also please post the rest of the line starting `terminating - reason: '-[__NSCFArray isFileURL]:`!  What's after the `:`?

Comment: More confusion.  You say you want to use the value typed in by the user and yet you are reading the value from a file?!?  You do realise that the user will need to type in a valid filename, given you use `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:]` to load the audio intervals?

Comment: Oh your bang on about the unrecognized selector, I just thought you were a mind reader!  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6820e20'. Ill post all of the code up in a sec.

Comment: Sorry when i say user (its only me) a bad choice of words im just creating a class that i can link up to the plists and artwork quickly by typing in dictionary val for artwork, sound etc - sorry i didn mean to confuse. ill load up the project) that will be quicker

Comment: OK, I want to know the type of `texttiming`.  Add this code after it's assigned: `NSLog(@"texttiming is %@", NSStringFromClass([texttiming class]));` (and post what it outputs).

Comment: @trojanfoe thankyou, I have updated the code and added the complete code for this test, including plist, the unrecognized selector error has gone :) however the array is empty.

Comment: OK, I don't see where `_sentance01Timing` is initialized within the `init` method?  It looks like it should be `sentance01Timing`?

Comment: Hopefully this is what you mean... sentance01Timing = **_sentance01Timing**; then I pass this to the nsstring NSString *Text01timing = [myDictionar objectForKey:_sentance01Timing]; it crashes if I use sentance01Timing

Comment: If you mean `@synthesize sentance01Timing = _sentance01Timing;` then that won't be called until **after** `init...()` has completed.  You probably want `sentance01Timing = _sentance01Timing` etc at the top of your `init...()` method after `if (self)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35366/discussion-between-natty-and-trojanfoe)

Comment: @trojanfoe many thanks i have go it going :D, I'm unsure how to upvote your suggestions (as im sure i wouldnt have got there without you pointing out the fact that i need to manually retain object within the custom init, ill write up the code corrections to reflect the changes. thanks for taking the time to help :) kind regards Natalie

Comment: Glad it's all sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to  trojanfoe I was able to fix the problem
the main problem was that my initialised objects wernt retained
if you do see a better way of things in the code please say as my goal is to learn (but baby steps! its all pretty new!!)
im doing this on my old mac laptop (so its not for arc - as i cant test it at the moment)
but maybe it will help someone else...

so creating my textmangerclass:

```
@interface TextManagerWithpageNum : CCLayer 
{
//create the properties you need notice the underscore 
//NSString *_varName;
NSString *_background;
NSString* _text;   //myText
NSString* _soundFile;
NSString* _audioInterval;
NSString* _currPageNumber;
}
```

declare the @property which gives access to the value accessor (getter) and mutator (setter)

```
 //@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString* background; - in arc
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* background;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* text;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* soundFile;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* audioInterval;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* currPageNumber;
```

and implementation .m

```
//@synthesize varName = _varName;
@synthesize background = _background;
@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize soundFile = _soundFile;
@synthesize audioInterval = _audioInterval;
@synthesize currPageNumber = _currPageNumber;

 -(id)initWithBackground:(NSString *)background   
      textFromPlist:(NSString *)text          
         soundNamed:(NSString *)soundFile     
 audioIntervalPlist:(NSString *)audioInterval
        CurrentPage:(NSString *)currPageNumber
  {
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {
    //_varName = varName;
    _text = text;
    _audioInterval = audioInterval;
    _soundFile = soundFile;
    _currPageNumber = currPageNumber;


      /*here is where I was having the problem - its important to manually retain
      and dealloc or you wont be able to use your objects created!*/

      //audio interval
  _audioInterval= [[myDictionary objectForKey:audioInterval]retain];//***please retain me! and dont forget to dealloc! :)
  NSLog(@"audio Intervals %@",audioInterval);
```

hello world

```
  TextManagerWithpageNum *Mypage = 
  [[TextManagerWithpageNum alloc]initWithBackground:@"Page01Bg.png"textFromPlist:@"Page01Text"soundNamed:@"Page01" audioIntervalPlist:@"AudioTimings" CurrentPage:5];                                               
 [self addChild:Mypage];
```

//hope the practicle example of where i stuffed up helps someone else
since its more fun to learn by someone elses mistakes :P